# Deploying files to a WEB Site that is already in PROD

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, deployment

I am new to ASP.Net development.

I need to maintain a site that is already working. I downloaded an ASPX and its correspondent ASPX.VB file, I edited it and uploaded it back to the site but it doesn't work.

How do I set my local project / page in order to make it interpreted and not pre compiled so I can upload those 2 files and make them work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can edit the .ASPX file since it is an HTML file, but can not amend the .vb file and take effect unless you recompile the project.

Comment: Those files in the server are not compiled and they work, I think they are interpreted some way. (I mean the ones already there).
Now, if I create new files I cannot upload only the ASPX and ASPX.VB, is there a wayt? If not, how do I compile and upload only these newly developed page to the current web site?

Comment: You can do the following:
1- compile the project again after amendments. 2- replace the .dll file of the project found in the bin folder of the project. 3-copy only the new .aspx files.

Comment: If the web site uses in-process session state and you update the site while people are using it, their session data will be lost. You can avoid that problem: [Pros and Cons of using ASP.NET Session State Server (instead of InProc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2714288/1115360)

Comment: Maybe I was not clear.
There is a site already working in an Hosting.
I want to add a new page to that site
The BIN folder is empty and if I download a page (APSX ans ASPX.VB and change those files and upload them to the server they work and the changes work).
I created a whole new project in Visual Studio 2019 and created just one page with its master file. I tried to upload the 2 ASPX and 2 ASPX.VB files and it throws an error. How can I make it work by uploading just those files?

Comment: @Damian That could depend on what the error message is.