# Issue for loading Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms in sub-directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-cookies, reportviewer, expired-sessions

Using **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms Version 15**
working normally however, for complaince we have **added path in ASP.NETSessionID cookie**
due to the path we have moved ReportViewerWebForm.aspx in the same folder[image]

Now, SSRS load with some of the things but get failed to load images/charts. Which loads from domain.com/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?querystring

How to add Same path in this URL so it get the session value and load the chart.

Fiddler result will help you to dig more in details 
[verify the red color 500 URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgMmU.jpg)

Those 500 error shows as [**ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewb1K.jpg) due to ASP.NET_SessionID has path, If we remove the path from cookie then it works, but for some compliance we have to add path

[SSRS report load but Report chart text is actually a chart and not able to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62RMc.jpg)

I really apperictat if some one can help me on this. I already missed the dead line and not able to deliver due to this bug.

Thank you in advance.

Fell free to contact me if required any more details.

Comment: Hi. This looks like problem with *session state*. Look at these links, I hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714288/pros-and-cons-of-using-asp-net-session-state-server-instead-of-inproc   ,   
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317604/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-store-asp-net-session-state

Comment: Hi Marko,

Thank you for your suggestion, However, we have to use stateserver with SessionIDManager
<i><sessionState mode="StateServer" stateNetworkTimeout="320" timeout="240" sessionIDManagerType="Namespace.MySessionIDManager" /></i>

which is our primary requirement.